# Пропорционально растягивающийся div элемент

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, html5, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы div растягивался 3:4?

Comment: [Resizable (aspect ratio)][1]

   [1]:http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#aspect-ratio

Comment: Ну, div - это блочный элемент... он не может растягиваться. Ни туда, и ни сюда))) Вы что-то другое имели в виду?

Answer (score 2):

Есть техника с использованием padding.
Пример - http://jsfiddle.net/2vqoprnr/

```css
.ball {
    width: 40%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    background: purple;
    position: relative;
}
.ball__content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball">
    <div class="ball__content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

можно менять высоту и ширину через стиль

```
var w = 100;
divEl.style.width = w + 'px';
divEl.style.height = (w * 3 / 4) + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ширина div'а относится к его высоте как 3:4
http://jsfiddle.net/fyryzb8L/1/

```
div {
    width: 10%; /* put any value here */
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
}

div:before {
    content: "";
    padding-top: 133.333%;
    float: left;
}
```